# Is there a Tumblr variable that refers to the blog's URL/username?

Tags: tumblr

I'm trying to do some stuff on my Tumblr layout, and I want some links to remain accurate regardless of whether the blog's URL later change. Either this is not possible from the [documented variables](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes) or, if it is possible, is done via another mean.

Is there a mean to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the name variable as long as it references the root "/"

```
<h1><a href="/">{Name}</a></h1>
```

Comment: {Name} is document as several things, and I failed to see this (completely) use in one of the examples for the {block:likes}: `<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/liked/by/{Name}">`. Looks like I got what I wanted. I just hope it works elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The `{Host}` variable returns the host name of the tumblr blog. For example, if the URL is `http://foo.tumblr.com`, `{Host}` will return `foo.tumblr.com`. Similarly, using `{Host}`  for custom domains,  i.e. `http://www.my-tumblr-blog.com` will return `www.my-tumblr-blog.com`.

You can use the following code for generating links:

```
<h1><a href="http://{Host}">{Name}</a></h1>
```

or better:

```
<h1><a href="//{Host}">{Name}</a></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works great for Tumblr themes, secondary blog was showing primary username but with this code it shows username of any blog (primary and/or secondary):

```
{block:NotReblog}<p>By <a href="{BlogURL}">{name}</a></p>{/block:NotReblog}
```